# Firebase auth with signInWithPopup not working on mobile device

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with the firebase.auth().signInWithPopup() function it works perfectly in the browser but on a real mobile device its not working at all. The popup opens for a quick second but then quickly closes. I think the problem might be with the OAuth redirect domains settings, because a device dosen't have a domain name. Does any of you have a solution for this ?

Comment: Are you using a framework like cordova or react native?

Comment: Currently popup and redirect operations are not supported on cordova. Until this feature is supported, you could use the native sdks (google, facebook, etc) to obtain the credential and then call signInWithCredential to complete the sign in to Firebase.

Comment: I did so, and its working now.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Firebase v3 dosen't support **firebase.auth().signInWithPopup()** and **firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect()** on mobile devices until then the solution is to use **firebase.auth().signInWithCredential()**.

Comment: What's alternative solution if I want Facebook login on device?

Comment: use firebase.auth().signInWithCredential()

Comment: Where is this documented?